# Python loop through table of URL's and get data from those websites

Tags: python, json

i'm trying to loop through a table that has all the websites that i want to get the JSON data from.

```
def getResponse(url):
    operUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    if(operUrl.getcode()==200):
        data = operUrl.read()
        jsonData = json.loads(data)
    else:
        print("Error receiving data", operUrl.getcode())
    return jsonData

def main():

    urlData = ("site1.com")
#Needs to loop all the URL's inside
#urlData = ["site1.com", "site2.com"] and so on

    jsonData = getResponse(urlData)

    for i in jsonData["descriptions"]:
        description = f'{i["groups"][0]["variables"][0]["content"]}'

data = data = {'mushrooms':[{'description': description,}]}

    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False), )
```

After running it saves it into a data.json file and here is what it looks like

```
{
    "mushrooms": [
        {
            "description": "example how it looks",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

It does get the data from the one site but i want it to loop through multiple URL's that are in a table like

EDIT:
i got it working by looping like this

```
for url in urlData:
```

and i have all my website links in a table urlData and after that appending the data found from those sites into a another table.

Comment: could you post an example of the json response you have?

Comment: When it gets the data it makes it into a JSON format `data = {'mushrooms':[{'description': description,}]}` and then pastes it into a file `with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False), )` Sorry i forgot to include this in the code above

Comment: update the question for better understanding :) If you post part of the exact content of `jsonData["descriptions"]` we can help

Comment: `for urlData in ["site1.com", "site2.com"]: jsonData = ` etc etc.

Comment: standard rule: if you work with `for`-loop then you have to use `list` to keep all results.

Comment: normal assigment `description = ...` can keep only one value - and this will be last value in `for`-loop. You have to use list to keep more values. before `for`-loop create list  `all_descriptions = []`, and lnside loop use `append()` to add result to this list -  `all_descriptions.append( description )`, and later add this list to `data = { ... }`

Comment: problem can be simpler if you put code in function to run `result = func(url)` and later run in `for`-loop like `all_results = []` and `for url in links: result = func(url) ;  all_results.append(result)` and later convert `all_results` to JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by looping like this

```
for url in urlData:
```

and i have all my website links in a table urlData and after that appending the data found from those sites into a another table. and after it's done it dumps the data into a json.